# A spiral tube shape by autodesk 3d max

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

How can I draw a spiral tube shape by autodesk 3d max like that
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about their logo or how to draw a spiral? And what have you tried?

Comment: @Ryan How to draw it by 3d max?

Comment: I tried to use a "Spring" in dynamic objects but didn't succeeded, because I want to use tube and I want to draw a horizontal spiral not vertical, I tried to use bend modifier, but didn't succeeded too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. Just go to **shapes** (next to geometry):

[image]

...then select the **Helix** tool:

[image]

Make sure to go to "top view" and draw the helix(it's a bit tricky). Anyways, once you draw it you will get this:

[image]

Then go to **modify panel** (see **yellow** arrow):

[image]

Make sure Your **Height** (under *Parameters*) is **0**. Adjust the *Radius 1* **or** *Radius 2* to your liking (see **yellow**):

[image]

Finally ,open up **Rendering** (in the same modify panel):

[image]

Make sure to check **Enable in view port** and **Enable in Render**. You can also adjust the thickness there.

Press **F9** to render and take your *Output*. It's as simple as that!

p.s. - Sorry about use of same images, my old pc is very slow.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your steps and I got solid Helix, but I want hollow Helix or tube Helix

Comment: I solved the problem by create copy of the solid Helix and reduce its radius and Boolean the two Helix